# please explain the meaning of the code style visibility

Tags: javascript, html

Good day! May I just please ask what does the code below mean, especially the part about (dialog.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";

```
dialog = document.getElementById("divName");
dialog.style.visibility = (dialog.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
```

Comment: This code ensures that if your div visible then it set it hidden and if it is hidden it set to visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **CSS Visibility**

My understanding of this style, is that you can hide something, but it still takes up the space it otherwise would, if it was shown.

Where `display: none` in essence "removes" the element from the document flow, like `position: absoulute` does.

[**Read more about the CSS visility style**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)

### **Ternary operator**

`var result = expression ? thisIfTrue : elseThisIfFalse`

```
dialog = document.getElementById("divName");
dialog.style.visibility = 
                  (dialog.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
```

The code above uses a ternary statement:

```
// If visibility is equal to 'visible' visible
dialog.style.visibility == "visible" 
            ? "hidden"    // then set it to hidden, 
            : "visible";  // otherwise set it to visible
```

[**Read more more about the ternary operator in javascript here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 0):

This code will toggle the [CSS visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) property for the HTML element with an id of `divName`.

The code `(dialog.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";` uses the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

In your context this has the same effect as using:

```
if (dialog.style.visibility == "visible") {
    dialog.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
else {
     dialog.style.visibility = "visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dialog is currently visible, then it will hide it. In the opposite, if it's not currently visible, then it will display it.

That is called an inline if-statement:
http://noobflash.com/javascript-inline-if-statement/

Answer (score 0):

The visibility property sets or returns whether an element should be visible.
The visibility property allows to show or hide an element. It is similar to the display property. However, the difference is that if you set display:none, it hides the entire element, while visibility:hidden means that the contents of the element will be invisible, but the element stays in its original position and size.